# How to determine what integer value of $j$ returns an integer when plugged in to $\sqrt{5j + 1}$ without trial and error?

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic, radicals, square-numbers

I am given $\sqrt{5j + 1}$ and I need to find what integer value of j evaluates this equation to an integer. I could only think of try and error by trying out different values of j incrementally to figure out the solution. Is there any other quicker way?

Comment: You want that $5j=n^2-1$ for some nonnegative integer $n$. Now, $5$ must either divide $n-1$ or $n+1$, but that's not all, of course.

Comment: Hint: using the equation $n^2 = 5j + 1$ find $j$ w.r.t. $n$.

Comment: Yeah, so $j = (n^2 - 1)/5$, but how do I then pick an n so that j is an integer. I just have to keep trying out different values of n.

Comment: Yeah, so $j = (n^2 - 1)/5$, but how do I then pick an n so that j is an integer. I just have to keep trying out different values of n @egreg

Comment: The last digit of $n^2$ must be $1$ or $6$. Write $n=10m+d$, where $d$ is an integer from $0$ to $9$. Just calculate $d^2$ for all these values, and the last digit of that will be the last digit of $n^2$.

Comment: If $5$ divides $n-1$, then $n=5m+1$ and so… If $5$ divides $n+1$, then $n=5m+4$ and so…

Comment: @Andrei I don't quite understand why we calculate $d^2$. If $n = 10m + d$, then $n^2 = (10m + d)^2$, where does calculating $d^2$ come from?

Comment: Modulo $5$ is better: writing $n=5k\pm1$, you can show $j=5k^2\pm2k$.

Answer (score 3):

If we write $n^2=5j+1$, we can see that every value of $n^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$. That means $n^2$ must end in $1$ or $6$, which implies that $n$ ends in $1,4,6,$ or $9$.

But our choice of $n$ is free; for every $n \equiv 1,4,6,9 \pmod {10}$, some $j$ exists that satisfies the equation.

Hence, rearranging such that $j = \frac15 (n^2 -1)$, you can plug in any integer ending in one of those digits. For instance, for $n=1,4,6,9,11,14,16,19$, we find $j=0,3,7,16,24,39,51,72$.

For each residue class, we ought to be able to find an even simpler expression. If we look at $n \equiv n^2 \equiv 1 \mod{10}$, we see that $n^2 -1 = 100k^2 +20k = 5(20k^2+4k)$, and hence $j = 4k(5k+1), \forall k$, and of course $k$ is just the digits preceding $1$ in $n$.

For $n=1,11,21,31,41,51$, we have $k=0,1,2,3,4,5$, and $j=4k(5k+1)=0,24,88,192,336,520$.

You should be able to apply the same solution method for $n \equiv 4,6,9 \pmod{10}$.

EDIT: Adding some additional thoughts.

This could have been simplified by ignoring base $10$ completely, and working in modulo $5$ instead. Then we only have two cases, $n= \pm 1 \pmod 5$. This will be the case for solutions in squares with a given divisor, so if for instance we were examining $n^2=13k+1$, we would want to use modulo $13$.

This is great so long as we are working with squares and adding $1$ (or another square); once we no longer can factor $n^2-1=(n+1)(n-1)$, things will get a lot more difficult. If we were looking at $n^5 = 7k +3$, I'm not sure where the best place to start would even be.

Comment: (For reference, though I suggest you check the calculations yourself: For $n=4,6,9 \pmod {10}$ respectively, $j=(10k+3)(2k+1), j=(10k+7)(2k+1), j=4(k+1)(5k+4)$. Note that in each case, these are simplified from $(10k+r+1)(10k+r-1)/5$, which is $(n+1)(n-1)/5$.)

Comment: Thank you! I am also confused whether it works for numbers other than 5 and $n^2$ also. What if we were dealing with $j = (n^8 - 1) / 7$? How would the scenario change now? Because n^8 - 1 can end in so many numbers, do we try all the digits from 0 to 9. like choose n from 0 to 9 and see which one works?

Comment: Actually, your example has fewer final digits than you think! $n^8$ always ends in $0,1,5$ or $6$. But something like $n^5$ or $n^7$ would definitely be a bit harder. At the same time, it's unlikely that $7j+1$ would catch many perfect powers (of any exponent) at all, because $7$ and $10$ are coprime, where $5$ and $10$ are not. I'm not sure $7\mid n^2-1$ for *any* $n$, though there are likely a few random $n$ where that divisibility holds. So something like $n^5=5j+1$ might easily solved, as $n \equiv n^5 \pmod{10}$ for all $n$.

Comment: Okay, so is there a generalization of what $n^{even number}$ might end in? Either way, will it be a maximum of 10 digits if we have $n^{even number} - 1$ that we have to check?

Comment: After thinking about it a bit, I think that the $(n+1)(n-1)/z$ form might be the best way to go after things for squares. For instance, above, every number of the form $5k \pm 1$ is a value of $n$; in the case of division by $7$, every number $7k \pm 1$ is an $n$. .... It seems likely that the number of digits examined is going to depend more on the divisor than the exponent, but I'm not entirely sure. Let's consider $n^3=5m+1$. In base/modulo $10$, the final digits of $n$ and $n°3$ are bijective: $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\} \mapsto \{0,1,8,7,4,5,6,3,2,9\}$ But (cont)

Comment: If we were examining $n^a= 17k+4$, though, we might prefer to work in modulo $17$, regardless of the exponent. Which means there are $17$ "digits" (actually residues) to check. I'm uncertain what the easiest direction is, though. ...... Finally, for even exponents, you will at maximum need to look at $0,1,4,5,6,9$, and at minimum $0,1,5,6$. Though again, working outside of base $10$ may be more convenient.

Answer (score 3):

What characterizes numbers which are one more than a multiple of $5$?

Answer: Such numbers have a $1$ or a $6$ in the ones digit.

What characterizes numbers whose squares have either a $1$ or a $6$ in the ones digit?

Answer: Numbers with either a $1$ or a $9$ in the ones digit have a $1$ in the ones digit of their squares, and number with either a $4$ or a $6$ in the ones digit have a $6$ in the ones digit of their squares.

Thus $j$ must have one of the four following forms where $k$ is any non-negative integer.

1. $j=\dfrac{(10k+1)^2-1}{5}=20k^2+4k$
2. $j=\dfrac{(10k+4)^2-1}{5}=20k^2+16k+3$
3. $j=\dfrac{(10k+6)^2-1}{5}=20k^2+24k+7$
4. $j=\dfrac{(10k+9)^2-1}{5}=20k^2+36k+16$

Here are results for $k=0,1,2,3,4$

[image: data table]

Comment: Don't forget that $k=0$ is also valid!

Comment: @EricSnyder You're absolutely correct.